# Google App Engine Parse Logs in DataStore Save to Table

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am new to GAE and I am trying to quickly find a way to retrieve logs in DataStore, clean them to my specs, and then save them to a table to be called on later for a reports view in my app. I was thinking of using Google Data Flow and creating batch jobs (app is python/Django) but the documentation does not seem to fit my use case so maybe data flow is not the answer. I could create a python script with BigQuery and schedule through CRON but then I would have to contend with errors and it would seem that there is a faster way to solve this problem.

Any help/thoughts/suggestions is always greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why you think dataflow won't fit your use case? Any specific problem? Regarding the BigQuery approach, what you mean "contend with errors"? What are those errors? Is your datastore data backed up in bigquery?

Comment: I do believe that Dataflow should be able to do the job.

Comment: @WillianFuks CRON Job errors that would delay writing the data to the table. To be more clear, it is not these issues could not be contended with I am just looking for a cleaner simpler solution. Since the logs already exist in the datastore I am just looking to clean and move it to a table. I am new to GAE and just started investigating Data Flow. I cannot find the examples to pull and clean. If you can point to me in the right direction that would be great!

Comment: have you also seen the possibility of [loading backups](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore) from datastore directly to bigquery?

Comment: @WillianFuks I see that you can load the data to a table in BigQuery but it appears I cannot append the data in the table. Ultimately, what I would like to accomplish is to load the cleaned data into a table and grow that table in a way that appends logs from the datastore every 15 minutes. Then I can build a user interface in my app with a date selector to render those logs to a view. Is there an example of this in the documentation? Can I use GAE in this way with Dataflow and BigQuery so I can reduce the code needed to produce the desired outcome?

Comment: can you share what your datastore data schema looks like? do you have a sample data that you can share or simulate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dataflow/Beam Python SDK to develop a pipeline that read entities from Datastore [1], transform data, and write a table to BigQuery [2]. To schedule this job to run regularly you'll have to use a third party mechanism such as a cron job. Note that Dataflow performs automatic scaling and perform retries to handle errors so you are not expected to manually address these complexities.

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/datastore/v1/datastoreio.py

[2] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py

Comment: This process will overwrite the data in the table I create in BigQuery every time the CRON process runs and scale as the log data increases? From what I understand Data Flow does not append. Sorry, I am just trying to understand the solution Google is providing. Once I have this data, I will be creating a log reports view that will dynamically change based on the date/date range the user provides.